# Publish .NET Library to Github packages with a name and the version

Tags: c#, git, .net-core, nuget, github-package-registry

I have created a .NET library C# project and published as a nuget package to my Github packages. The published package doesn't show the correct naming and version in **Assets**.

I created a NuGet.config in the project folder. Then followed

`dotnet pack --configuration Release`

`dotnet nuget push "bin/Release/OctocatApp.1.0.0.nupkg" --source "github"`

Expectation: `OctocatApp.1.0.1.nupkg`

Actual : `package.nupkg`

I followed [Github Reference](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/packages/using-github-packages-with-your-projects-ecosystem/configuring-dotnet-cli-for-use-with-github-packages#publishing-a-package). Can anyone help me to identify what is going wrong with the step? or is there anyway to set a display text in Assets?

[image: GIT Assets Example]

**Edit: Adding .csproject configuration & nuget.config**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <PackageId>OctocatApp</PackageId>
    <Version>1.0.0</Version>
    <Authors>Octocat</Authors>
    <Company>GitHub</Company>
    <PackageDescription>This package adds an Octocat!</PackageDescription>
    <RepositoryUrl>https://github.com/*****/PackageDemo</RepositoryUrl>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

**nuget.config**

```
<configuration>
    <packageSources>
        <clear />
        <add key="github" value="https://nuget.pkg.github.com/****/index.json" />
    </packageSources>
    <packageSourceCredentials>
        <github>
            <add key="Username" value="My Name" />
            <add key="ClearTextPassword" value="***************" />
        </github>
    </packageSourceCredentials>
</configuration>
```

Comment: You should include the source code of the GitHub Action config you are using.

Comment: show us your csproj

Comment: @Polygnome added the info.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's a weird problem.

See on [github.community](https://github.community/t/asset-name-is-always-package-nupkg-on-github-package-registry/14645) for more mentions of the same problem, and [here](https://github.community/t/asset-name-is-always-package-nupkg-on-github-package-registry/14645/7) for a solution.

Essentially use the [GPR .NET Core global tool](https://github.com/jcansdale/gpr) for pushing to the GitHub package registry.